# Unexpected result from elasticsearch Phrase suggester when first letter is misspelled

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm using Elasticsearch Phrase Suggester for correcting user's misspellings. everything is working as I expected unless user enters a query which it's first letter is misspelled. At this situation phrase suggester returns nothing or returns unexpected results.

My documents and query are exactly the same with examples of [phrase suggester](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html):

```
POST test/test?refresh=true
{"title": "noble warriors"}
POST test/test?refresh=true
{"title": "nobel prize"}

    POST test/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "noble prize",
    "simple_phrase": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "title.trigram",
        "size": 1,
        "gram_size": 3,
        "direct_generator": [ {
          "field": "title.trigram",
          "suggest_mode": "always"
        } ],
        "highlight": {
          "pre_tag": "<em>",
          "post_tag": "</em>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example when first letter is misspelled:

```
   {
  "_shards": ...
  "hits": ...
  "timed_out": false,
  "took": 3,
  "suggest": {
    "simple_phrase" : [
      {
        "text" : "mobel prize",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 11,
        "options" : []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Example when 4th letter is misspelled:

```
{
  "_shards": ...
  "hits": ...
  "timed_out": false,
  "took": 3,
  "suggest": {
    "simple_phrase" : [
      {
        "text" : "noble prize",
        "offset" : 0,
        "length" : 11,
        "options" : [ {
          "text" : "nobel prize",
          "highlighted": "<em>nobel</em> prize",
          "score" : 0.5962314
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your generator's prefix length.

> prefix_length
>
> The number of minimal prefix characters that must match in order be a candidate suggestions. Defaults to 1. Increasing this number improves spellcheck performance. Usually misspellings don’t occur in the beginning of terms. (Old name "prefix_len" is deprecated)

A warning, generally setting prefix length on fuzzy matching queries like this to zero tends to have a pretty significant adverse affect on performance.